# Unterschied die Parallelisierung und das Parallelisieren

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Ich bin vorhin über die Formulierung des folgenden Satzes gestolpert:

> Gegenstand dieser Arbeit wird die Parallelisierung des Lösens
>   von gewöhnlichen Differentialgleichungen [...] sein.

Zuerst stand dort `Lösung` statt `Lösen`, was denke ich falsch ist, 
da der Vorgang des Lösens parallelisiert wird, die Lösung einer Gleichung ist etwas vollkommen anderes.
Nun frage ich mich wie es sich mit der Parallelisierung verhält, muss der Satz zu

> Gegenstand dieser Arbeit wird das Parallelisieren des Lösens
>   von gewöhnlichen Differentialgleichungen [...] sein.

umformuliert werden? Ich sehe hier keinen Unterschied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da sich *»die Lösung einer Gleichung«* nicht notwendigerweise auf das Ergebnis bezieht, sondern auch den Vorgang des Lösens meinen kann, ist *»Lösung«* in den beiden Sätzen durchaus verwendbar, wäre aufgrund der Zweideutigkeit allerdings die schlechtere Alternative.

Zwischen *»die Parallelisierung«* und *»das Parallelisieren«* sehe ich keinen Bedeutungsunterschied, beides ist der Vorgang des Parallelisierens.

Comment: Dass Lösung auch den Vorgang beschreiben kann sehe ich ein, das Lösen empfinde ich dennoch als treffender. Den Bedeutungsunterschied bei Parallelisierung und Parallelisieren habe ich ebenfalls nicht gesehen, weshalb ich verunsichert war.

Comment: @nlsmrg: Auch ich halte _»Lösen«_ für die bessere Wahl, habe die Antwort ergänzt.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference between "Parallelisierung" and "Parallelisieren" is, that "Parallelisieren" focuses on the process and "Parallelisierung" on the result. Another example would be "entdecken". "Das Entdecken" is a process and "Entdeckung" is the result.

Comment: Zwischen _»Das Entdecken eines Käfers unter dem Sofa«_ und _»Die Entdeckung eines Käfers unter dem Sofa«_ sehe ich keinen Bedeutungsunterschied.

Comment: @Pollitzer Der Unterschied ist gering - aber vorhanden.  Vgl. auch "Rechnen", "Rechnung", "Erinnern", "Erinnerung", "Vergemeinschaften", "Vergemeinschaftung" usw.

Comment: Dass das Parallelisieren den Prozess betrifft, da stimme ich zu. Das Resultat des Prozesses ist aber Parallelität, nicht Parallelisierung. Jemand, der den Prozess nicht gesehen hat, weiß nicht, dass eine Parallelisierung stattgefunden hat - vielleicht waren die Gleichungen von Beginn an parallel? Eine überzeugende Alternative habe ich leider nicht in petto.

Comment: In diesem Zusammenhang ist der Prozess gemeint, also ist Parallelisierung oder Parallelisieren schon die richtige Wahl. An die Parallelität hatte ich bisher nicht gedacht.

Comment: @SearchSpace: Bitte versuche auf Fragen, die auf Deutsch gestellt wurden, auch auf Deutsch zu antworten. Dies hier ist ein Deutsch-Forum. Beachte auch: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/830/1487

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ok.